# Webpack's CommonsChunkPlugin and the use of "import * as"

Tags: angular, webpack, webfont-loader, commonschunkplugin

I am learning Webpack for quite a while and came across a weird behavior.

As described in the [Webpack Introduction on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) 
I am importing all my vendor modules into the `vendor.ts`-file, all polyfills into the `polyfill.ts`-file and initialize my app within the `main.ts`-file. 
Thus, I added the following entry points and the CommonsChunkPlugin in my config for Webpack:

```
// webpack.config.js -->

entry: {
    'polyfill': './src/polyfill.ts', 
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
}

// ...

new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfill']
})
```

Consequently, Webpack should realize that `vendor.ts` and `app.ts` has common modules in use and add it to the `vendor.js`-file only. The `vendor.ts`-file does look like this:

```
// vendor.ts -->

// Angular 2.
import '@angular/platform-browser';

// ...

import '@angular/router';

// RxJS.
import 'rxjs';

// Web Font Loader.
import * as WebFont from 'webfontloader';

// Font Awesome.
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

Unfortunately, this behavior works as expected with all modules that I imported via `import MODULE`, but does not work with modules that I imported via `import * as ALIAS from MODULE`. In this example the `webfontloader`-module is written into `app.js` as I also import it there, although it should have shared dependencies with the `vendor.ts`-file as well.

```
// app.ts -->
// Initialize Angular.
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

// Load Fonts.
WebFont.load({
   google: {
       families: ['Lato:400,700']
   }
});
```

When I change `import * as WebFont from 'webfontloader';` to `let WebFont = require('webfontloader');` it does work.

What's wrong? Why are all imports of angular working then?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same syntax in the vendor.ts as the Angular imports, e.g.: `import 'webfontloader'` instead of `import * as` seems to work. Everything ends up in vendor.js as expected. To be honest I don't know the technicalities of why it works like that.